# windows authentication using forms in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I want to authenticate users based on the windows user name and password,  in a form, to check whether the username and password entered is a valid windows user(if possible, an user of particular domain), how  can i do that in silverlight

Answer (score 0):

Leo,

If you use Windows Authentication, IIS is going to prompt for the User Name and Password the server running your app doesn't recognized the credetials of the user from their the machine they are urnning the application from.